# How can I programmatically change the IP address of an Azure Cloud Service or VM?

Tags: azure, proxy, ip-address, vpn

Background. I have a service that is crawling a partners website. Their website blocks "bot like" behaviour by IP Address. They don't control their servers themselves, so they want me to change IP address of my crawler often (e.g. every minute). The crawler is currently running as an Azure Cloud Service.

So my question is. How would you programmatically change the IP address of an Azure server?

I could use a Proxy... but the site is running on SSL, so I'm not sure this is an option.

I could use a VPN connection... but I'm not sure if it's possible to programmatically dial a VPN from within a Cloud Service/VM? I'm using C#/.NET.

Finally. I tried to do a VIP Swap, which actually gives me a new IP in seconds. But unfortunately this only works when swapping form Staging to Production. I get an error when trying to swap from Production to Staging, if there is no staging running. Why is this blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot programmatically change a deployment's IP address, aside from shutting down the deployment (which releases the IP address) and then re-starting it (and that you *can* do programmatically, or through PowerShell). Also note that if you have several Virtual Machines in the same deployment, each VM will share the same public IP address.

Note that with Virtual Machines (vs. web/worker role cloud services), if you have a single Virtual Machine, you *can* stop the VM, then restart it, and you'll get a new IP address (ok, actually, there's no guarantee you'll get a different IP address, so more accurately you'll be *assigned an IP address*) while retaining the state of your VM. Shutdown and startup are not an instantaneous operatios however, and it's not going to provide you a per-minute IP address (and your VM will end up being offline shutting down or starting up pretty much all the time), so it won't satisfy your requirement.